# How to create object of a child class in a parent class without hardcoding in Python?

Tags: python, class, object, inheritance, parent-child

Im completely new in Python. I have a function in a parent class. I want the function to return a child class object, without hardcoding. I don't know how to achieve that.

```
class Parent(self, name, password)
  self.name = name
  self. password = password

  def create_child_class():
     d1 = Child()

class Child(Parent)
  super.__init__()
```

If I want to import the child class in the parent class, it shows an error: "(most likely due to a circular import)". I want to create the child object without hardcoding and I don't know how to do that. Please help me to solve it.
Thank you.

Comment: What's the actual end goal here? Why do you need this behavior as it doesn't make any sense form design *PoV*. A class shouldn't know anything about its (possible) subclasses.

Comment: Conceptually, how is the parent class supposed to pick the child class to instantiate? What if there are multiple child classes? The current code sample isn't valid python; please correct it to create a [mcve].